# How to add new fields and use input values from these fields and pass all fields to a function in R Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, stringr

I have a Shiny app that takes in two input fields `Latent variable` and `Indicators` which is pasted in the server side and renders the output. I would like to add multiple ui input fields of `Latent variables` and `Indicators`.

To give some context, the lavaan function creates latent variables with a specified latent variable name and its related indicators. So each latent variable name or `latent variable` is connected with the `indicators`.

I would like to create multiple pairs of `latent variables` and `indicators` to add to the model.

For example I would like to type in "visual" and select "x1", "x2", and "x3". Then, I would click a button to add `latent variable` and `indicators` field, and then I would enter "textual" and select "x4", "x5", and "x6". Eventually, I would like to add more fields.

Then on the server side, these lines will be pasted as new lines and be added to the model.
Would this be possible?

Here's the code for the app:

```
library(shiny)
library(lavaan)

ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Text Input"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            textInput(inputId = "text1", 
                      label = "Latent Variable"), 
            selectInput(inputId = "select1",
                        label = "Indicators",
                        choices = "",
                        multiple = TRUE)),
                         
        mainPanel(
           verbatimTextOutput("text1"),
           verbatimTextOutput("regout")
        )
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    updateSelectInput(session, "select1", choices = names(HolzingerSwineford1939))
  })
    
  syntax1 <- reactive({input$text1})
  
  syntax2 <- reactive({
    
    paste("=~", paste(input$select1, collapse = " + "))
    
  })
  
  syntax <- reactive({paste(syntax1(), syntax2())})
  
  formula <- reactive({
    tryCatch({
      syntax()
    }, error = function(e) NULL)
  })
  
  
  model <- reactive({
    if(!is.null(formula()))
    tryCatch({
        cfa(formula(), data = HolzingerSwineford1939)
      }, error = function(e) NULL)
    })
  
  results <- reactive({
    if(!is.null(model())){
      summary(model(), fit.measures = TRUE)
    }
  }) 
    
    output$regout <- renderPrint({
      results()
    })
  }
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Yes.  It should be possible using  [modules](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html).  here, the module could contain your `Latent variable` and `Indicator` inputs.  You can then create an arbitrary number of instances of the module to manage your arbitrary number of latent variables.

Comment: Modules are a good tool. Have a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62813162/12647315). You can take this as a starting point and would have to add a `return` to the module logic and store the results from the modules in the main app.